# How to construct an orthogonal, complete set of functions on the interval $[0, L]$ with given conditions at $x=0,L$?

Tags: functional-analysis, orthogonality, orthogonal-polynomials

The functions must be at least $C^2$, preferably $C^\infty$. Completeness for square-integrable functions is sufficient. 
The conditions at the points $x=0,L$ prescribe the values of the function and its derivatives.

In my case I need simply $f(0)=f(L) = 0$ and $f'(0)=f'(L) = 0$, but I wonder whether one may consider the general case of arbitrarily prescribed values $f^{(n)}(0)$ and $f^{(n)}(L)$?

Does it get easier if I prescribe the values at $x=0$ and demand periodicity, i.e. $f^{(n)}(L)=f^{(n)}(0)$ up to some order $n$?
Literature recommendations are welcome. Thank you in advance.